# Finding the maximum sum of a decreasing Arithmetic Progression

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

> Find the maximum sum of the AP $40+38+36+34+32+...$

**My Attempt:**
$a=40$
$d=(-2)$
$S_n= \frac{n}{2}[2a+(n-1)d]$
$S_n= \frac{n}{2}[80+(n-1)(-2)]$
$S_n= n[40+(n-1)(-1)]$
$S_n= n[41-n]$
$S_n= 41n-n^2$

I can find the answer by differentiating the expression and finding the maxima but is there any other way obtaining the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is. If you think for a second you understand that as soon as your progression hits 0, it will start adding negative numbers  therefore decreasing its sum. So the maximum sum is $S_{20} $.

Comment: Oh right, how dumb of me to not think of that!

Comment: @OsheenSachdev sometimes we overestimate a problem! We must always try to think in the simpler terms possible!

Answer (score 1):

As $n$ integer, find when $$\dfrac{d(41n-n^2)}{dn}>=<0$$

Comment: Thank you, but as I said I know how to use differentiation for this question but I wanted another way.